# Error in modal after moving project files

Tags: angular, typescript, android-emulator, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I have a problem with modal in my nativescript project after I moved few project files around, including the modal. I rewrited the imports. I also removed any compiled js files so it could recompile my project correctly.

I do not really know what the error means but it has something to do with modal showing function that returns promise for the modal set value.

**app/components/register/register.component.ts**

```
import { Component, ViewContainerRef } from "@angular/core";
import { AuthService } from "../../shared/services/auth.service";
import { ModalDialogService } from "nativescript-angular/directives/dialogs";
import { DatepickerModalComponent } from "../../shared/components/modals/datepicker/datepicker.modal.component";


@Component({
    selector: "register",
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: "./register.component.html"
})
export class RegisterComponent {

    private date;

    constructor(private auth: AuthService, private modal: ModalDialogService, private ref: ViewContainerRef) {}

    pickItem() {

    }

    pickDate() {
        let opts = {
            context: {},
            fullscreen: false,
            viewContainerRef: this.ref
        }
        this.modal.showModal(DatepickerModalComponent, opts).then(res => {
            let pickerDate = res;
            let dateString = pickerDate.toISOString().slice(0,10);
            this.date = dateString;
        });
    }

    submit() {

    }
}
```

The problem lies in the `this.modal.showModal()` in `pickDate()` function, which is invoked from the registration page.

**app/shared/components/modals/datepicker/datepicker.modal.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalDialogParams } from 'nativescript-angular/directives/dialogs';


@Component({
    selector: "date-picker",
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: "./datepicker.modal.component.html"
})
export class DatepickerModalComponent {

    private date;

    constructor(private params: ModalDialogParams) {}

    close() {
        this.params.closeCallback(this.date);
    }

    onPickerLoaded() {
        this.date = new Date();
    }

    onDateChanged(args) {
        this.date = args.value
    }
}
```

Here is the modal itself most important is the `close()` function which is passing the modal set value.

**Error**

```
core.umd.js:1708 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: detachedProxy.getChildrenCount is not a function
TypeError: detachedProxy.getChildrenCount is not a function
    at file:///data/data/org.nativescript.secura/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/directives/dialogs.js:82:31
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.secura/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js:388:26)
    at Object.onInvoke (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.secura/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:3841:33)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.secura/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js:387:32)
    at Zone.run (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.secura/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js:138:43)
    at file:///data/data/org.nativescript.secura/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js:883:34
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.secura/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js:421:31)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.secura/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:3832:33)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.secura/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js:420:36)
    at Zone.runTask (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.secura/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js:188:47)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.secura/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js:595:35)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.secura/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js:500:21)
    at ZoneTask.invoke (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.secura/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js:485:48)
    at timer (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.secura/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js:1561:29)
    at invoke (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.secura/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/timer/timer.js:19:48)
```

I would be really happy if someone could help me with this I have spent a lot of time on this.

Comment: If you are using the latest nativescript-angular (6.x and above) use this application as reference on how to create and use modal pages in Angular https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/tree/master/e2e/modal-navigation-ng

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after migrating to latest version of angular (>=7) and nativescript (>=5). Inside the DatepickerModalComponent's template for sure he has this component:

```
 <DatePicker (loaded)="onDatePickerLoaded($event)"></DatePicker>
```

So, removing the already registered selector `date-picker` will solve the problem.

Try to change from:

```
selector: "date-picker"
```

to

```
selector: "my-prefix-date-picker"
```

Comment: Hi there, please [edit] your answer to add a little bit about how your code will help OP. thanks :)